# How can access I macOS again?

Tags: macos, mojave

I have a Macbook Pro mid 2014 and I just want to install Linux (CentOS) as a dual boot on it.

In selecting a partition I've shrunk my macOS drive to install Linux. But after installation I can’t see macOS partition in startup manager.  I don’t know if I accidentally erased my macOS drive or did something else?

Is there any chance my macOS still exists?

Comment: There's already many questions on this site with answers for this question.  Have you searched for them and tried the answers already provided?

Comment: Probably.  To see, suggest you run:  diskutil list; from the terminal.

Comment: If you can boot to Linux, post the output from `fdisk -l /dev/sda`.